# Parametric family of cubics with Galois group $C_{3}$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

In the Wikipedia page for [Generic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_polynomial), there is an example of a cubic polynomial parametrized with one variable $t$ that has an associated Galois group $C_3$:

$$x^{3}−tx^{2}+(t−3)x+1$$

However, this particular polynomial doesn't cover *every* cubic polynomial with Galois group $C_3$. So, how can we construct a parametrized cubic polynomial in two variables that can cover all cubic polynomials with arbitrary coefficients and Galois group $C_3$?

Comment: Which one it doesn't cover?

Comment: I'm thinking in something like $x^3-7x^2+2x+8$, with discriminant $86^{2}$

Comment: You could replace $x$ with $ax+b$ and still get a polynomial with group $C_3$, right? That might cover everything.

Comment: You might have a look at Steve Balady, Families of cyclic cubic fields, Journal of Number Theory, Volume 167, 2016, Pages 394-406, ISSN 0022-314X,
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2016.03.011.
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X16300580)
Abstract: We describe a procedure for generating families of cyclic cubic fields with explicit fundamental units. This method generates all known families and gives new ones.
Keywords: Cyclic cubic fields; Fundamental units

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, rgval?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks for the ref. I read Balady's paper and it's more clear now. One just need to construct an action for $C_{3}$ as a linear fractional transformation, and the extra parameters can be included in the transformation. It became clear after seeing the action $1/(1-t)$ in Serre's Topics in Galois Theory and how to add more parameters to it.